# how to generate randon in a specific range( between 0 and 1)

Tags: matlab

I need to Generate 50,000 uniform random numbers between 0 and 1 using MATLAB’s function rand. what I did is

```
r = randi([0 1],1,50000)
histogram(r);
```

instead of getting number between 0 and 1, such as 0.5, 0.3, I only get 0 and 1. What is the right way to do it? I looked up online but I cannot find anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

`randi` generates a random integer. Use `rand()` to generate a random number in the interval `(0, 1)`. For other ranges, you can use one of the following approaches:

- Generate a random integer with the range `[A B]` with `randi`
- Generate a random number with `rand()` and scale it to your desired range by multiplying; this will include decimals throughout the range.

Check out [MATLAB's documentation on randoms](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/random-number-generation.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
xmin = 0
xmax = 1
n = 50000
r = xmin+rand(1,n)*(xmax-xmin);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
r = rand(50000,1);
histogram(r);
```